# How to avoid iterating over Nil value

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I'm trying to scrape a website's content to instantiate objects out of the data, and I'm running into a problem with a dead link on the page I'm scraping. I want to figure out how I can simply not iterate over that link and avoid scraping it altogether.

I tried using this, but it didn't work:

```
name = li.css("strong a").text.strip unless li.nil?
url = li.css("a")[0].attr("href") unless li.nil?
Player.new(name,url)

class HomepageScraper
  BASE_URL = "https://www.nba.com/history/nba-at-50/top-50-players"

  def self.scrape_players
    page = open(BASE_URL)
    parsed_HTML = Nokogiri::HTML(page)
    name_lis = parsed_HTML.css("div.field-item li")
    name_lis.each do |li|
      name = li.css("strong a").text.strip
      url = li.css("a")[0].attr("href") 
      Player.new(name,url)
    end
  end
end
```

I expected example output to be:

```
@name = "Shaquille o neal", @url = "www.nba..."
```

But received:

```
@name = "Shaquille o neal", @url = nil
```

The error message is:

```
undefined method `attr' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

Comment: i guess li.css("a")[0] is nil of any value and that's why it is giving error.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Don't create `Player` unless `url.nil?` is false. It's better to only store good values than to store anything and later have to clean up the mess to avoid further problems. I'd use `select` or `reject` checking for `nil` instead of `each` so then only populated `url` values are looped over.

Comment: Note that when asking about a problem with your code, we expect to see enough information and code so we can duplicate/test the problem. Please read "[ask]" and the links at the bottom of that page, along with "[mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)". Following those guides will help us help you. Failing to do so wastes our time as we load the page, look at the HTML to compare your accessor to what's actually there, write test code for a solution, etc. That'll turn off a lot of potential helpers who'll instead work on another problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `compact` method on Array.

It is a useful method if you need to remove nil values from an array.

For example:

```
[1, nil, 2, nil].compact => [1, 2]
```

In your case:

```
name_lis.compact.each do |li|
end
```

Comment: just tried giving that a tried and received this error: undefined method `compact!' for #<Nokogiri::XML::NodeSet:0x00007fa77310c0f8> (NoMethodError). i get the same thing with .compact as well

Comment: Please provide output of `name_lis`

Comment: If `name_lis` is a `Nokogiri::XML::NodeSet` instance, try `to_a` to convert to an array before passing to `compact`.

Comment: @Rhunal: [#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fff510ed3b0 name="li" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fff510ed144 name="strong" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fff510ece88 name="a" attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3fff510ecdfc name="href" value="http://www.nba.comhistory/legends/profiles/kareem-abdul-jabbar">] children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fff510ec6cc "Kareem Abdul-Jabbar">]>]>]>,Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fff504899fc name="strong" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fff50489790 "Shaquille O'Neal">]>]>>]

Comment: I'd counter than using `compact` is a knee-jerk reaction to having inserted bad values which wasted CPU and memory, though those might be small in a single iteration of the code, they add up when code has to run for days.

Answer (score 0):

If you run at least Ruby 2.3, do a

```
url = li.css("a")[0]&.attr("href")
```

This sets url to nil, if the part to the left of `&.` is nil, and applies `attr` otherwise.

Comment: Or: `li.at("a")[:href] rescue nil`

Comment: This would hide other bugs, for instance if `li` is nil or any other exception which might occur.